# One React Component. Two HOCs. How to make setState correctly update props?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Given a standard compose function and a 'div' Component, how would you write the two HOCs such that:

- The 'div' element starts as a 20px green box, then on click, becomes a 50px blue box.
- The concerns of - a: merging state with props, and b: triggering a state change, are handled by separate HOCs.
- the updater HOC maps state to props, and sets a default state
- the dispatcher HOC accepts a function to get the new state on click

The example below works to get a green box, and correctly fires the handler.  The update only happens in the state of the Dispatcher HOC's state.  The updater HOC's state remains unchanged, as do its props.

I'm really curious to understand what's happening.  Flipping the two HOCs' order in compose causes the handler not to be set.  Since they both merge in `{...this.props}`, that doesn't make sense to me.  Guessing there's something I don't understand about how multiple HOCs merge props and state.

```
const HOCDispatcher = myFunc => BaseComponent => {
  return class Dispatcher extends React.Component {
    constructor(props,context){
      super(props,context);
      this.handlerFn = (event)=>{this.setState(myFunc)}
    }
    render(){
      return createElement(BaseComponent,{...this.props,onClick:this.handlerFn});
    }
  }
}

const HOCUpdater = defaultState => BaseComponent => {
  return class Updater extends React.Component {
    constructor(props,context){
      super(props,context);
      this.state = Object.assign({},defaultState,this.state);
    }
    render(){
      return createElement(BaseComponent,{...this.props,...this.state});
    }
  }
}

const MyComponent = compose(
  HOCDispatcher(()=>({
    style:{width:'50px',height:'50px',background:'blue'}
  })),
  HOCUpdater({
    style:{width:'20px',height:'20px',background:'green'}
  }),
)('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to simplify or compile your code in a way to a less complicated structure you can understand it better:

**The initial version of MyComponent**

```
const MyComponent= class Dispatcher extends React.Component {
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.handlerFn = (event)=>{this.setState({
      style:{width:'50px',height:'50px',background:'blue'}
    })}
  }
  render(){
    return <HOCUpdater onClick={this.handlerFn}/>
  }
}
```

Where `HOCUpdater` also renders as:

```
class Updater extends React.Component {
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state = {
      style:{width:'20px',height:'20px',background:'green'}
    };
  }
  render(){
    return <div style:{width:'20px',height:'20px',background:'green'}/>;
  }
}
```

Thus rendering the green box.

**After triggering the click**

```
const MyComponent= class Dispatcher extends React.Component {
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.handlerFn = (event)=>{this.setState({
      style:{width:'50px',height:'50px',background:'blue'}
    })};
    this.state= {
      style:{width:'50px',height:'50px',background:'blue'}
    };
  }
  render(){
    return <HOCUpdater onClick={this.handlerFn}/>
  }
}
```

If you pay attention to the render, it's still the same because `this.props` has not changed and it is still empty. Thus no change to the style of the box whereas the state of the `Dispatcher` is changed!

Did you see where you went wrong? Well, just change `this.props` to `this.state` in the `Dispatcher` and you'll see the magic happen.

**But wait, there's more!**

What happens if you have a line of code like this?

```
createElement('div',{
  style:{width:'50px',height:'50px',background:'blue'},
  style:{width:'20px',height:'20px',background:'green'}
});
```

Well, it still renders the first one (the blue box) but to avoid this try changing the render method of `HOCUpdater` to this:

```
return createElement(BaseComponent,{...this.state});
```

and also add a `componentWillReceiveProps` method, so your `HOCUpdater` will look like this:

```
const HOCUpdater = defaultState => BaseComponent => {
  return class Updater extends React.Component {
    constructor(props,context){
      super(props,context);
      this.state = Object.assign({},defaultState,this.state);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      this.setState(nextProps);
    }
    render(){
      return createElement(BaseComponent,{...this.state});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer Amin! Re:"Well, just change this.props to this.state in the Dispatcher and you'll see the magic happen."  Agreed. 
 Doesn't that mean the dispatcher is now also mapping state to props?

Comment: It worked to merge state into props in the dispatcher.  However, that's the concern I'm trying to separate by creating two HOCs.  If I understand what's happening now, props are copied between HOCs in the render function, but state, and other properties on the constructor, are not.  The only way to merge state from different HOCs is by merging each HOC's state into props.  Does that match your understanding?